# Google Drive API - File access after OAuth

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

My schoolmate generated a client id on Google dev console for our app. We are using OAuth. Basically we would like to access files on google drive. So, with HIS auth credentials / and file id on his drive - it's ok, but with my auth credentials / my file id on my drive - it says 
"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup".
Also I enabled drive api on my google drive, and still nothing. Also im now an owner of the app registered on google dev console.

What am i missing?

```
function checkAuth() {
      gapi.auth.authorize(
     {
       'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
       'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
       'immediate': true
     }, handleAuthResult);
}
```

Where CLIENT_ID is from dev console

File access :

```
function readFileWithSpecificId() {
  var id = parse('id');
  console.log(id);
  var file = {
    downloadUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + id
  };

  if (file.downloadUrl) {
     var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr2.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200)
         {
          if (xhr2.responseText)
           {
             var contentData = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
             contentFromDrive = contentData;
             proj = contentData.project;
             risk = contentData.risks;
             task = contentData.tasks;
             console.log("project data: ");console.log(proj);
             console.log("risk data: ");console.log(risk);
             console.log("task data: ");console.log(task);
             dataLoader();
            }
         }

       };
       xhr2.open('GET', data.downloadUrl, true);
      xhr2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      xhr2.send();

    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {

    };
    xhr.send();

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: What am i missing?  your code.  we cant help you without it.

Comment: Code added, i hope this helps